# Проблемы с родительский классом

Tags: java, ооп

Существует родительский класс `player` и субкласс `wolf` 
В классе `wolf` есть метод `kill();`
Как можно использовать метод `kill();` в классе `player`?

Comment: Объявить его там.

Comment: Если `kill()` объявлен как `static` - `Wolf.kill()`. Если нет - `Wolf wolf = new Wolf(); wolf.kill()`

Comment: создать класс/интерфейс `Entity`, определить в нём метод `kill`. и без всяких наследований: просто внутри класса с помощью полей определите тип сущности, которую вы хотите описать. как это сделать? это уже совсем другой вопрос.